# Why is this Annoying Line interfering with my output?

Tags: c, fork, stdout, flush, fflush

I have this piece of code that I developed just to address a problem that I have in another large program that I am developing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void processLine (char []);
void readLine(char []);

const int LIMIT = 512;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char oneLine[LINE_MAX];
    readLine(oneLine);
    
        
    return 0;
}
void readLine(char line[])
{
    processLine(line);
    printf("Annoying line\n");
}
void processLine(char line[])
{
    
    pid_t process;
    int child_status;

    string input;
    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input;

    
        process = fork();
        if(process == 0)
        { // do nothing
        }
        else 
        {
                        //parent
                    if(input == "quit")
            {
                printf("Quit command found ! \nExiting ");
                    
                for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
                {
                    printf(".");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    sleep(1);
                    
                }
            
                printf("\n");
                    exit(0);            
            }
            else
            {
                wait(&child_status);
            }
        }
    
}
```

My goal is simple, When the user enter quit.

I will just display

> Quit command found
>
> Exiting **...**

And there is a delay of one second between each of these three dots.

However the output that I get is

> Quit command found
>
> Exiting **. Annoying line..**

I wonder how come this Annoying line Prints after the first dot, even though it's from the calling function and it is not it's turn to get printed to the terminal ????

Any ideas. I spent 10 hours trying to fix this

Comment: I think the parent process still goes on after the fork and prints that line. The child has terminated fine... Note the Annoying Line comes after the first dot, as then the child sleeps and the parent gets CPU time, returns and prints.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie , so how would I work around this ?

Comment: Do not print the `Annoying Line`. What do you want to work around anyway? It is correct code.

Comment: In my original code, I have to keep printing after I call the processLine function, I only did this code to address this problem

Comment: But what is the problem? You print a line and now complain about the fact that it printed a line? Seriously? Maybe it's that your understanding of what `fork()` does is flawed. Maybe returning to that code is the fault?

Comment: Is there away to terminate the program in the parent process without having to go back again and printing this annoyling line ?? I want it to be printed for any other input except when the user inputs quit !!

Answer (score 1):

In the child process your `// do nothing` falls through and returns to `main()` and prints the line.  `fork()` makes two copies which both continue executing.  Often the child calls `exec()` immediately to run something else (never returning), but you aren't doing anything like that.

Comment: how would I fix this ? In my original program, I am doing a lot of things in the child process but still same behaviour happens

Comment: @Pro: Call `exit()` when you're done in the child process.  The same way you're avoiding printing `Annoying line` from the parent.